# Where to find SimpleJPARepository implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

The official Spring Data [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html) says that SimpleJpaRepository is the "default implementation of the CrudRepository interface".
I assume this means that SimpleJpaRepository provides the actual code that we need to be executed to perform CRUD operations.

However, I cannot find the actual implementation (I mean, the code itself) of SimpleJpaRepository.

Can anyone tell me where to find it (or tell if my assumptions are wrong) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

Comment: Which is not the JPA API. This is Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all Spring Projects on GitHub:

https://github.com/spring-projects/

The SimpleJpaRepository can be found in the Spring Data JPA repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot !

Comment: Great. Can you please mark my answer as the correct answer. Thank you